# What happened to Juliet's cats?

Tags: plot-explanation, psych

In S01E02 of *Psych*, we meet Juliet for the first time inside some type of diner. Shawn "reads" her during his one-sided conversation and before he realizes that she is a Detective. During this "reading," he mentions that Juliet has two cats, a black one and a grey one. However, later, we don't hear any mention of those cats, not even after Shawn moves in with Jules. So, what happened to them? I don't recall any mention of them after that first episode...

Comment: At least one of them was mentioned later; in one of the Christmas episodes, the gift Shawn gives Juliet references that one of the cats had passed away/been put to sleep recently. And as I don't recall Juliet confirming the two cats suggestion, it's possible there was only one grey-and-white one.

Comment: @AllisonC - Nah, I'm pretty sure that there were two cats...